# User not logged out when shutting down Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am currently managing 3 devices with Windows 10: Asus VivoBook, Samsung, and Lenovo ThinkPad. There is one peculiar behavior with the Asus one. Whenever it is turned off, the current user is not logged out so everytime the laptop is turned back on, that user is automatically logged in. This only happens in the Asus one, not in the Samsung or Lenovo notebooks. This is a bit annoying for other users that use the Asus notebook. I've tried looking for the settings in Display Options or the Power Options. I've compared those settings between the 3 devices, but I can't find any differences. Am I missing something?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

**Edit 1**:
The behavior was not unique to Asus. It was the same with Samsung and Lenovo. The difference was that the Asus notebook has **more than 1** user. The other two notebooks only has 1 user. When I add more users to the other two notebooks, the behavior persist in all three notebooks.

I've tested the issue with this scenario. I logged in to user A, then restart the notebook. After it restarted, I logged in to user B, then I restart the notebook. When trying to restart with user B, a message popped up saying other user are still logged in and might lose their work if I restart. I restarted anyway. After it restarted for the second time, I logged back in to user B, then tried to restart, the same warning message popped up.

Next I try manually logging out. I logged back in to user A, **logged out**, logged back in to user B, then I restart the notebook. The notebook went straight to restart with no message popping up. After it restarted, I logged back in to user B, **logged out**, then shut down from the login page. There are no warning message and the notebook went straight to shut down.

So apparently the last user shutting down (without logging out from) the notebook automatically logged back in whenever the notebook was turned on. This is annoying because if another user uses the notebook and tries to shut down, there will be a warning message, but it's not clear if that warning was because someone genuinely left some work while logged on or they simply forgot to log out.

I've tried looking and tweaking in Power Options and Sign-in Options. I've also tried "netplwiz", but I still can't find a way to make it that whenever any user shut down, don't automatically logged them back in. Is it possible that this is a bug in Windows 10? Do I have to resort to telling all users to always finish their work and log out whenever they're done or risk losing their work when another user shuts down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do all 3 of your devices have passwords?

Comment: The user is absolutely logged out.  The user is just configured to automatically login.  **Its not possible for a user not to be logged out during a restart or shutdown.** The only other explanation is the machine is actually going to sleep or being suspended instead of being shutdown.  Windows notifies the user which event is happening

Comment: to add to Ramhound, the setting you are looking for OP is the Auto Logon setting in the User section - this isn't a power related option so you won't find it there.

Comment: In addition to the above, look to see if the problem computer has another Administrative user that may be trying to do updates.  I have seen this.

Comment: @QuickishFM Can't find anything relevant in the Sign-in Options. Also nothing in User Accounts.